# Wagtail Form static fields & superuser-only page

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I did not found any answer to this. So is there a way in Wagtail to have an `AbstractEmailForm` without `AbstractFormField` (for example, can I hard code them into `AbstractEmailForm`? I know that `AbstractEmailField` has some variables that `Django` requires). I just need to have a contact form only with `email` field, I dont need to set fields dynamically.

And the second question: How do I set permission for that form page so that only superuser can edit the form page?(And the translated version too? There are a lot of answers to this, but I don't actually understand how to do it with `AbstractEmailForm`).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hard-coding your form fields, then the Wagtail forms module doesn't really give you anything that you don't already get from [Django's forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/), and so you're better off using Django forms directly. The `serve` method on a Wagtail page is equivalent to a Django view function, so any form-processing logic that would normally go into a view function can be placed in `serve`.

There's an example of this here (but written for Wagtail 1.x, so imports will need adjusting): https://github.com/gasman/wagtail-form-example/commits/master

Comment: thanks for your answer! I want to use Wagtail forms ModelAdmin panel to export as CSV and other. Can I somehow combine Django forms and Wagtail's FORMS panel(with CSV export)?